# Matematical model for lung ventilation simulation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to create a programatical simulation for respirator ventilation of a lung. Therefore I've read [this paper](https://www.scirp.org/pdf/jbise_2015102014265203.pdf). As this is my first big math problem, I need some assistance to make sure I understand the math part correctly.

[image]

If I understand it correctly, this equation can be used to calculate the pressure and flow values to build a graph like this:

[image]

But I think I do miss something here.
If I know all resistance and compliance values, I can calculate a specific value. So I would get a value for each time point, like 10ms, 20ms and so on. But how do I get a pressure and a flow value? As far as I understand this, I do get the ratio of I/P.

I don't understand (p. 711)

> Therefore, the transfer function has expressed the airflow output as a function of pressure input I(s)/P(s) using
> the transform function in Equation

Comment: The transfer function is in the sense of the Laplace transform. Or if you replace $s=D$ with the derivative operator, then you get a fraction in the operator algebra. There are also replacements with difference operators to get a related discrete system.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'm sorry, but I did not understand your comment.

Comment: For instance a transfer function $\frac{1+s}{1+2s}$ stands for the input-output system $y+2y'=x+x'$, $x$ the input signal, $y$ the output. Higher degree of $s$ gives higher order derivatives.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Oh. Thanks for that. I didn't know about transfer function. Now I understand a bit more. So with some values (R and C) set I do get: I(s)/P(s) = (s^2 + 420s) / (s^2 + 620s + 4000). My input is pressure (P) and I should get the air flow (I) - if I understand you correctly. So I just use e.g. s = 10 cmH2O and do get the flow value for this pressure?

Comment: Perhaps this maple worksheet will help: [MSE_Q4838031](https://maple.cloud/app/5915042132393984/MSE_Q4838031)

Comment: @gpmath Wow. Thank you for that. That's heavy stuff for me. I'll try to understand everything.

Comment: @gpmath I tried to understand the worksheet. From where do you get the P function (7)? And it would be great if you can give an explanation or a link how to get from (7) to (10). I really want to understand and learn this, but I didn't get the point...

Comment: @gpmath If I understand this correctly, you have added a pressure function. In my case I need to use a pressure function like this (top left): https://media.springernature.com/m685/springer-static/image/art%3A10.1007%2Fs00101-004-0708-y/MediaObjects/s00101-004-0708-yflb4.gif , which is a e^-n function for the inspiration

Comment: @user3142695 $P(t)$ is defined in the paper (1)(2)(3). But I used it with no slope $\tau=0$ in (14) of the worksheet.
The step response of the system is defined as $\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{H(s)}{s}\right](t)$

Comment: @user3142695 It's no problem to simulate the state-space model with a arbitrary pressure function. But tell me, how do you want to simulate your model? With Matlab/Simulink, Python or something else?

Comment: @gpmath I need to build a script. In this case it will be a web application which should simulate ventilation. So I have to use javascript for this.

Comment: @user3142695 Then you'll need an ODE solver library for Javascript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150676/discussion-between-user3142695-and-gpmath).